# How can you burn an ISO image on a USB Flash Drive using K3b?

Tags: usb, iso

I'm quite new of Ubuntu... 
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and what I want is to burn a Windows ISO image on a USB Flash Drive. 
Now, using the default Startup Disk Creator, seems that it doesn't recognize ISO images different from Ubuntu (or at least, I try to select the Windows ISO but nothing really happens). Then I've installed K3b but, then again, this time the problem is that it seems to not recognize media different from a CD.
I'm sure that there's a way to do it with K3b and I'm just missing it. Anybody can help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/289559/22949) If it's *really* important that the "burning" (writing) be done with k3b and not other software, I recommend editing your question to clarify that and also to explain more specifically what your needs are. Writing an image to a USB device is significantly different from burning it to a CD/DVD, and I doubt k3b has a feature for this. And even if it did, it would likely not produce bootable media from a *Windows* ISO image.

Comment: No, there's actually no need to do it with k3b. Indeed I set my sights on Unetbootin and almost worked out... If it wouldn't have been for the fact that its current version doesn't support the "show all drivers option" any more. Which was necessary for the application to see the actual USB drive since, as required for the Windows installation, I had to previously format it to ntfs using Gparted. But apparently Unetbootin recognizes only drives formatted to fat32 with which the windows setup doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't burn an arbitrary ISO image to USB stick. Technically, you can, but it will not boot. For image to boot, it must have special USB-ish header, in which case it is called a "hybrid" image.

Is you image hybrid? If yes, just use `dd` command to copy it directly to your USB device, like:

```
dd if=EvilOS.iso of=/dev/sdh
```

Be *very careful* with what you put for the `of` argument (which will *not* necessarily be `sdh`) and read some manual on `dd` beforehand.

If no, find instructions specific to OS you want to put on USB. You will need to run some scripts or change ISO content in the process.

Comment: I guess that it might be the reason why it seems that so many people creating bootable USB drives with Unetbootin can't actually boot it afterwards. How do I know if the ISO image is hybrid? I don't really know what you mean by USB-ish header...

Comment: If the image is hybrid, this is usually boasted somewhere in description. Most major Linux distros go in hybrid images nowdays. Window$ does not. Unetbootin is created exactly to use with non-hybrid images - it tries to parse them and fails on this a lot.